# Import site from HTML pages (currently static files in directories, not in a CMS)

Tags: migrations, importing-exporting

I've taken over a small website ([link here](http://www.givingwhatwecan.org/), in case it helps) which is currently composed of largely static HTML files (with a few PHP includes thrown in to generate menus and footers, etc). I want to migrate it into Drupal, as I'm fairly familiar with this and it'll make the site more manageable. My question is: what's the best way to do this?

I've found plenty of modules to migrate sites from CMSes like WordPress, but none to import static files organised in directories. Some research turned up the Migrate and Feeds modules, but I'd like some guidance on whether to use something else, or whether to use these, and if so how. Should I write a perl script to pull out the content and titles and current paths or pages into a CSV of some format? Presumably others have done this, so it'd be interesting to see best practice, or examples...

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised that you didn't find [Import HTML](http://drupal.org/project/import_html) yet. Personally, I haven't used it since the Drupal 5 days, but just give it a try and see if it does what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot, somehow that didn't turn up when I searched. I'll look into it and see if it meets our requirements...

Comment: No problem. I'd love to read how it works for you.

Comment: Well, this was clearly the right option as I've had it working a few times and it's done a good job. That said, user beware: getting the module to work consistently has been a challenge.